# Applying Maybes When Updating A Model

Tags: elm

I want to update my model this way:

```
updatedModel =
  if model.firstChord && model.secondChord then
    { model | firstChord = {}, secondChord = {} }
  else
    model
```

the firstChord and the secondChord both are of the type Chord:

```
type alias Chord =
{   root : Maybe Pitch
,   third : Maybe Pitch
,   fifth : Maybe Pitch
}
```

The pitch type looks like:

```
-- pitch
type alias Pitch = ( PitchName, PitchLevel )

-- pitch name
type alias PitchName = String

-- pitch level
type alias PitchLevel = Int
```

My initial Model has these fields:

```
{ firstChord =
    {   root = ( "C", 3 )
    ,   third = ( "E", 3 )
    ,   fifth = ( "G", 3 )
    }
, secondChord =
    {   root = ( "F", 3 )
    ,   third = ( "A", 3 )
    ,   fifth = ( "C", 4 )
    }
```

I like to have optional pitch values.

How can I update my model giving it a value OR nothing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `type PitchName = A | B | C | ... | G`. And `type Pitch = Pitch PitchName PitchLevel`. Then `somePitch = Pitch G 3`

Comment: If firstChord and secondChord are of type  Chord then `firstChord = {}` would be illegal because {} is not of type Chord.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what are you looking for. I guest you would like to have a Maybe Chord like this.

```
type Pitch =
    Pitch String Int

type alias Chord =
    { root: Maybe Pitch
    , third: Maybe Pitch
    , fifth: Maybe Pitch
    }

type alias Model =
    { firstChord: Maybe Chord
    , secondChord: Maybe Chord
    }

init: Model
init =
    { firstChord =
        { root = Pitch "C" 3
        , third = Pitch "E" 3
        , fifth = Pitch  "G" 3
        }
    , secondChord =
        { root = Pitch "F" 3
        , third = Pitch "A" 3
        , fifth = Pitch "C" 4
        }
    }

update: Model -> Model
update model =
    case (model.firstChord, model.secondChord) of
        (Just first, Just second) ->
            { model | firstChord = Nothing, secondChord = Nothing}
        _ ->
            model
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `Maybe a` type, such as `Maybe Pitch` you have two ways to set its value: `Nothing` or `Just a`. So instead of this:

```
{ firstChord =
    {   root = ( "C", 3 )
    ,   third = ( "E", 3 )
    ,   fifth = ( "G", 3 )
    }
, secondChord =
    {   root = ( "F", 3 )
    ,   third = ( "A", 3 )
    ,   fifth = ( "C", 4 )
    }
```

...you need to do this:

```
{ firstChord =
    {   root = Just ( "C", 3 )
    ,   third = Just ( "E", 3 )
    ,   fifth = Just ( "G", 3 )
    }
, secondChord =
    {   root = Just ( "F", 3 )
    ,   third = Just ( "A", 3 )
    ,   fifth = Just ( "C", 4 )
    }
```

Of course, you then use `Nothing` so indicate no value:

```
firstChord =
    {   root = Just ( "C", 3 )
    ,   third = Just ( "E", 3 )
    ,   fifth = Nothing
    }
```